# query for fetching values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I am having two tables questions and tags  each questions are associated with many tags
I want to fetch a question and related tags using a query.
I am not getting how to fetch it.

```
questions 
qid ques
Q1  abc
Q2  rst 


tags
id  tag   qid
T1   css   1
T2   html  1
T3   java  1
T4   php   2
T5   c++   2
T6   html  2
```

I want result as

```
Q1 abc   T1   css   1
         T2   html  1
         T3   java  1
```

q1 abc should not repeat with tags

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 2):

if you question have at least one tag use `INNER JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Question a
        INNER JOIN tags b
            ON a.qid = b.qid
-- WHERE a.qid = 1
ORDER BY a.qid, b.id
```

but if tag is optional and you want still the question to be shown in the result list, use `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.*, b.*
FROM    Question a
        LEFT JOIN tags b
            ON a.qid = b.qid
-- WHERE a.qid = 1
ORDER BY a.qid, b.id
```

Comment: it is giving proper output, But can we remove repeating of qid and ques as above result i want

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
SELECT q.qid,q.ques,t.id, t.tag,t.qid FROM questions AS q JOIN tags AS t WHERE q.qid = t.qid
```

Comment: You forget to explain the jointure, it's `LEFT JOIN table1 on table1.id = table2.id2` ...

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT ques,tag FROM quesions t1,tags t2 ON t1.qid = t2.qid
```